# Information [18]: Select at least one signature

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, scp

While performing `run` / previewing classified image in SCP, the statement `Information [18]: Select at least one signature` appears. What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the boxes for the classes you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try cheking if you have selected the correct band set.